# puppeteer works locally but results in cloudflare protection when running from aws ec2 ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have a script written in nodejs using puppeteer and its working fine locally in headless mode. However, once I deploy it on my aws ec2 (ubuntu server), it stopped working. After a couple of tries I logged out the "page.content()" and figured out there was a cloudflare protection showing. How can I bypass that and why its not detected puppeteer when I run the script locally?

Comment: The same issue... Trying different fixes but nothing helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the user pguardiario is right and the traffic is blocked by cloudflare, then one of the ways to solve the problem is to bypass the protection.

To do this, install the library data and using the code below you will return the ashml of the page.

Libs:

```
npm i puppeteer-extra puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth puppeteer
```

nodejs:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')
const pluginStealth = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')
const { executablePath } = require('puppeteer')

const link = 'https://www.g2.com/'

const getHtmlThoughCloudflare = async (url) => {
  puppeteer.use(pluginStealth())
  const result = await puppeteer
    .launch({ headless: true })
    .then(async (browser) => {
      const page = await browser.newPage()
      await page.goto(url)
      const html = await page.content()
      await browser.close()
      return html
    })

  console.log(` HTML: ${result}`)
  return result // html
}

getHtmlThoughCloudflare(link)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because cloudflare blocks datacenter traffic. You could use a residential proxy I suppose.